# How to print out API info into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, ajax

This question regards a university homework project.

I need to print out in HTML some information about a public API. I have managed to call on the public API and print out the list of radio channels into the menu on the left (no click function added yet), but now I need to show the current schedule for the day for each channels. The schedule are supposed to show inside the html tag "info".

I'm struggling because of the API link in the tag `scheduleurl`. How can I show each channel's schedule for the day when I click on each channel in the menu?

*Things to know:* I'm not allowed to modify the HTML file. My own js code starting point is marked by a comment.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="se">
<head>
    <title>Sveriges Radio</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="mainheader">
        <div class="contain">
            <h1 id="logo">DT084G - Projekt</h1>

            <section id="player">
                <select id="playchannel" class="form-control"></select>
                <button id="playbutton" class="btn btn-primary">Spela</button>
            </section>
            <!-- /#search -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.contain -->
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>SR - Sveriges Radio</h2>
        <div class="left">
            <section class="clist">
                <h3>Bläddra via kanal</h3>
                <nav id="mainnav">
                    <ul id="mainnavlist"></ul>
                    <div class="spacer" id="shownumrows">
                        <label for="numrows">Max antal: </label><input type="number" id="numrows" value="10" min="1" max="2000">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
            <!-- /#lan -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.left -->

        <div class="right">
            <div id="info"></div>
            <!-- /#info -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.right -->

        <footer>
            <p>Projektuppgift för kursen DT084G, Introduktion till programmering med JavaScript.</p>

            <div id="radioplayer"></div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My so far written js code:

```
   // Denna fil ska innehålla er lösning till projektuppgiften.

"use strict";

/*  Delar till ej obligatorisk funktionalitet, som kan ge poäng för högre betyg
*   Radera rader för funktioner du vill visa på webbsidan. */
//document.getElementById("player").style.display = "none";      // Radera denna rad för att visa musikspelare
//document.getElementById("shownumrows").style.display = "none"; // Radera denna rad för att visa antal träffar

/* Här under börjar du skriva din JavaScript-kod */



// HERE STARTS MY CODE


// variabler
var mainnavlistEl = document.getElementById("mainnavlist");
var i;
var restUrl = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/channels/?format=json";

//funktion för ajax-anrop navigation vänster
window.onload = loadData;




function loadData() {

    //ajax-antop
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        //check for answer
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var jsonStr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var channelsArr = jsonStr.channels;
            
            //navigation vänster
            // Inkluderat unika id och tagline för varje alternativ

            for (i = 0; i < channelsArr.length; i++) {
                // element
                document.getElementById("mainnavlist").innerHTML += "<li id='" + channelsArr[i].id + "' title= '" + channelsArr[i].tagline + "'>" + channelsArr[i].name + "</li>";
                
            }


            console.log(channelsArr);

        } else {
            mainnavlistEl.innerHTML = "Fel vid anrop: " + xhr.status;
        }
            // Dropdown list
            // Inkluderat unika id och tagline för varje alternativ
        for (i = 0; i < channelsArr.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("playchannel").innerHTML += "<option id='" + channelsArr[i].id + "'" + "title='" + channelsArr[i].tagline + "'>" + channelsArr[i].name + "</option>";
        }
    }

    //Send Ajax

    xhr.open('GET', restUrl, true);
    xhr.send(null);

    
}

// schedule

//variabel för id


document.getElementById("mainnavlist").addEventListener("click", function infoData(e){

    var URL = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/scheduledepisodes?channelid=" + e.target.id + "&format=json&indent=true";
 
    //document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = URL ;
    var idEl = document.getElementById("mainnavlist");
    var restUrl2 = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/scheduledepisodes";

   
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onclick = function () {
        //check answer 
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            var jsonStr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var scheduleArr = jsonStr.title;

            for(i = 0; i < scheduleArr.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += "<p>" + scheduleArr[i].title + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    
    xhr.open('GET', URL, true);
    xhr.send(null);

    
})
```

[Data inside the "scheduleurl tag in the channels json file](http://api.sr.se/api/v2/scheduledepisodes?channelid=164&format=json&indent=true)

An example for one of the channels in the public API structure:

```
0: {image: "https://static-cdn.sr.se/sida/images/132/2186745_512_512.jpg?preset=api-default-square", imagetemplate: "https://static-cdn.sr.se/sida/images/132/2186745_512_512.jpg", color: "31a1bd", tagline: "Talat innehåll om samhälle, kultur och vetenskap. …ng och upplevelser till exempel i form av teater.", siteurl: "https://sverigesradio.se/p1", …}
1:
channeltype: "Rikskanal"
color: "ff5a00"
id: 163
image: "https://static-cdn.sr.se/sida/images/163/2186754_512_512.jpg?preset=api-default-square"
imagetemplate: "https://static-cdn.sr.se/sida/images/163/2186754_512_512.jpg"
liveaudio: {id: 163, url: "http://sverigesradio.se/topsy/direkt/srapi/163.mp3", statkey: "/app/direkt/p2[k(163)]"}
name: "P2"
scheduleurl: "http://api.sr.se/v2/scheduledepisodes?channelid=163"
siteurl: "https://sverigesradio.se/p2"
tagline: "P2 är den klassiska musikkanalen som även erbjuder jazz samt folk- och världsmusik. Digitalt sänder vi musikprogram dygnet runt, i FM finns även program på andra språk än svenska."
xmltvid: "p2.sr.se"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I dont understand how I can call on the API that is in each channels "scheduleurl" when its different (the id) for every channel.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the name.  You need to get the other items and add the also.  e.g.  part of the code:

```
// On click pass id to the function
function myFunction(id) {

// put id in a variable
var id = id;

//use the variable in the url
    var url = `http://example.com?id=id`;

 // loop through elements for this id
     for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = response[i].id;
                        var slug = response[i].slug;
                        var excerpt = response[i].excerpt.rendered;
                        var link = response[i].link;
    
    //put them all together in a variable in the html format you require
                        
    var tr_str =
                         
                         '<td>'+
                        '<div class="card" style="width: 250px;">' +
                        '<div class="card-divider">' + id + ' ' + slug + '</div>' +                    
                         '<p>' + excerpt + '</p>' +                          
                        
                        
                        '<a href="'  + link + ' " target="_blank">'+                   
                        '<input type="button" value="read more" style="margin-right: 15px;">' + 
                        '</input>' +
                        ' </a>' +
                   
    
    
                        ' </div>' +
                         '</div>'+
                           '</td>' 
                            
    
                                
                            ;
    
    //append the variable to the dom element
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += tr_str;
```

Comment: Yes I know im only getting the name right now and on the left it should only be the name there. When i click on one of the channels to the left, then the channels schedule should show for that channel to the right in the "info" tag in the html.
how do I write so I will pull the info from that API link in the scheduleurl tag?

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to listen for the click event, pass the details as a parameter to the function and then append the ajax response to the info div. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: ok i read throught your code but struggling abit. Im gonna be clear what i need to do so no confusion from my side: Right now i have my left side menu showing just the names of the channels. each channel have the correct id from the API assigned to each channel. When I click a channel I want that channels schedule show in the info tag. Sorry im im not understanding exactly what ur code does :P

Comment: I edited the code a bit.  Maybe another user will then be able to give a clearer answer for you.

Comment: I will see if i can get ur code suggestion to help thanks for now! If I manage to solve it I will reply here otherwise Im still stuck :p thanks!

Comment: I have updated my code, why isnt this working to in this example to fetch and show a programs title from the schedule?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had to revise my answer, I think finally I understand what you want to do.

I'd replace for loop part of your code:

```
// create variable for the markup
let markup = '';

// using 'for of' loop for readibility
for (const channel of channelsArr) {
    markup += `<li class="mainnavlist__item" id="${channel.id}">${channel.name}</li>`;
}

// once you have the whole markup constructed, replace the html content.
document.getElementById("mainnavlist").innerHTML(markup);

// now you would need an event listener, for example
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("mainnavlist__item")) {
        // this function will render info html
        showInfoData(event.target.id);
    }
})

function showInfoData(id) {
    // you need to gather the details you want to render into the info tag. This will give back the details of the clicked channel from the array, or here call another API, depends on from where you get the info
    let currentChannel = channelsArr.filter(channel => channel.id === id)[0];

    let infoMarkup = currentChannel.tagline;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML(infoMarkup);
}
```

You also need to make sure to empty the info's innerHTML when you need to hide it (click outside, or on a close btn, etc). I hope I understood you right.

Comment: Why isnt my updated code working?
when i click a channel, i tried with a short innerHTML and then i could atleast print out the correct API adress which also updated the link with the correct id for the element i clicked, but why isnt this working? 
Shouldnt this code print out a for loop of all the titles for the schadule of the channel?

Comment: Are you sure you always get the e.target.id value on clicks? You use no filter to view clicked target. Are you sure your API call gives back data as intended? Also, using "innerHTML +=" will always destroy the child elements and you will only get the last value in a paragraph. It's pointless to use "+=", you should use simple assignment if it's your intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not the best at either JavasSript or handling JSON, but maybe you could just consider me a rubber ducky of sorts, then it might lead you to a nice solution.

I went to the api url and looked at the data.  It seems to me that the schedule portion of the json (hash, dictionary, what have you) is simply a link to THAT specific data... (which happens to be xml).

What I would do, if I were you, is before parsing the JSON into a string, I'd try to grab the schedule url, and and parse the xml into a useful format while parsing the JSON.

Once again, I'm not the best at this, but like rubber duckies, I do squeak. What do you think?

Comment: I have updated my javascript code, why isnt this working? Im also adding a link to the API json file which is inside the API scheduleurl tag in the edited file below the js file

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble understanding what you want to achieve, but if it seems like you have made a successfull call to an API, and managed to display the names of the radiostation(?) in a list. What you want to do next i to be able to click on the items in the list on the left side, and then display some information on the right side?

The information you want to display should come from a API call to e.g:
"http://api.sr.se/v2/scheduledepisodes?channelid=163"

Now, what you are struggling with is how you can do this, and how to specify which ID to use when you call the API?

You already have the different ID's (the radiostation ID that goes on the end of the scheduleUrl string) as you HTML id for your list elements, right?

What i would do it create a listener event on your list elements. This listener should make a XHR-request to the scheduleUrl. You can use the ID from the HTML list element that you click as argument for you API call.

```js
function listener(event){
  url = "http://api.sr.se/v2/scheduledepisodes?channelid=";
  id = event.target.id;
  new_url =  url + id;
  
  // Make a new XHR-request here
  // and display the received infomration
  // where you want


}
```

However, to make this work, there are a few changes you need to make to your code.
When creating your list-elements, you use 'innerHTML'. This is not the best choice.
You should rather create an HTML DOM object, and then append this element to the 'unordered-list' element.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

You can also set the id, and other attributed directly to this 'child element'.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

It is when you create the list-elements you should add the event listener.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

So, to summarize:

1. You should change how you create you list-elements
2. You should add an click-listener to the list elements
3. The click listener should make a XHR-request based on the list-elements id (which is the same as the radiochannel id)